# Android Emulator - Android is starting.. Optimizing app xx of xx

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to run the application on emulator, it says '**Android is starting**' '**Optimizing app xx of xx**' and results in qemu exception.
See images for reference.

[Optimizing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8I5A.png)

[qemu exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyfmi.png)

Is there any way to either '*stop optimizing*' or '*do it faster without exception*'?

Thanks